# How to extract all the lines containing a matching word from a website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an url, say http://www.bbc.com/news/world/asia/. Just in this page I wanted to extract all the sentences (or two sentences each before and after) that has India or INDIA or india (should be case insensitive).

Comment: Define "line" very carefully

Comment: add code snippet and elaborate more about your problem.